# How to pass data from parent to child component multiple times in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am loading data from an array in my parent component and passing it to child components multiple times. I noticed the first item from the array is sent to the child but afterwards the rest of the components are not being passed/received to/by the child. Here is the sample of the code I use to access the array:

```
{(() => {
switch(data.questions[this.state.index].question_type) {
    case "RadioQuestion":   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.radioQuestions[this.state.index]));
                            return <RadioQuestion
                                      radioQuestion = { this.state.radioQuestions[this.state.index] }
                                      handleRadio = { this.handleRadio } />;
    case "TextQuestion":   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.textQuestions[this.state.index]));
                           return <TextQuestion
                                      textQuestion = { this.state.textQuestions[this.state.index] }
                                      handleText = { this.handleText } />;
    case "FileUpload": return <FileUpload index = { this.state.index } />;
    default: return <h2>Unknown Question Format</h2>
}
})()}
```

I have logged (console.log()) the data from the respective arrays above the correct items are being loaded from the arrays using the index.

In the respective children, it seems the state is not being updated after adding the first element:

```
// Radio Component
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        radioQuestion: this.props.radioQuestion
    };

    this.handleRadioText = this.handleRadioText.bind(this);
    this.handleRadioSelect = this.handleRadioSelect.bind(this);
}

// Text Component
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        textQuestion: this.props.textQuestion
    };

    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
}
```

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Would appreciate any feedback, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Mark20 I checked your sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/4x5x6oo054 , can help me to understand your problem ?  i am not clear with it

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G solved it thanks, for offering some help

Answer (score 0):

React does not know your array has been changed since its immutable. what you can do is create an another array and add new value to it and pass it to the Child component. Since this does not contain the full code, i will show an example how to do that

```
 var newArray = this.state.arr.slice();    
 newArray.push("new value");   
 this.setState({arr:newArray})
```

Comment: I am not changing my array, I am just passing data at index = 0 to the child component then data at index = 1...array.length but only the first element appears, the rest are being ignored but when I log the data[index] I get the correct output. It’s only passing data after the first entry it’s not being sent to the child component.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.radioQuestions[this.state.index]));` does this work correctly ?

Comment: Yes it works properly as I mentioned in the question, here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/4x5x6oo054

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have requirement to pass data at index = 0 to array.length then you can use the map function to render the child component till the array length

{(() => { array.map((a, index) => {
  switch(data.questions[this.state.index].question_type) {
    case "RadioQuestion":   
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.radioQuestions[index]));
      return <RadioQuestion 
                radioQuestion={ this.state.radioQuestions[index] }
                handleRadio = { this.handleRadio } />;
    case "TextQuestion":   
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.textQuestions[index]));
      return <TextQuestion
                textQuestion = { this.state.textQuestions[index] }
                handleText = { this.handleText } />;
    case "FileUpload": return <FileUpload index={ index } />;
    default: return <h2>Unknown Question Format</h2>
 }
})})()}
```